# How do I auto-update date and time in django?

Tags: python, django

This is my Django project.
How do I auto-update date and time? My code is allowing user to update it manually?

```
class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,auto_now=False)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set auto add to both fields True.

```
class Join(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Use ModelAdmin.exclude to exclude fields from the form.
E.g

```
class JoinAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ('timestamp','updated',)
```

Docs here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.exclude